# List Comprehension with multiple procedures

Tags: list, haskell, list-comprehension

Im really new to haskell and trying to learn the Basics, now I wanted to try
little bit of list comprehension.

I want to create an list (not ending) with uneven numbers from `0 to …` where `` number `mod` 13 == 3 `` and `` number `mod` 20 == 5 ``.

Then I want to use the `take` function and take the first 5 numbers of this list
and show them.

My Code was this:

```
take 5 [x | x <- [0..], odd x == False, x > 0, x `mod` 13 == 3, x `mod` 20]
```

Now I'm getting errors in haskell and dont really know what do to:

```
> <interactive>:14:19: error:  
    • No instance for (Num Bool) arising from the literal ‘0’  
    • In the expression: 0  
      In the expression: [0 .. ]  
      In a stmt of a list comprehension: x <- [0 .. ]  
<interactive>:14:25: error:  
    • No instance for (Integral Bool) arising from a use of ‘odd’  
    • In the first argument of ‘(==)’, namely ‘odd x’  
      In the expression: odd x == False  
      In a stmt of a list comprehension: odd x == False
```

Does somebody know how I can make it correctly?

Comment: `x \`mod\` 20` is not a Boolean.  See your last guard in the list comprehension.

Comment: `odd x == False` is also equivalent to `even x`. This will however make your list unable to find the first 5 items, since no even number mod 20 can ever give an odd result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is because of `x`mod`20`. This expression returns a Num type and your need a Bool. If, for instance, you want to compare the modulus result with 0:

```
take 5 [x | x <- [0..], even x, x `mod` 13 == 3, x `mod` 20 == 0]
```

Answer (score 3):

The culprit is in the last part:

```
take 5 [x | x <- [0..], odd x == False, x > 0, x `mod` 13 == 3, x `mod` 20]
--                                                              ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Here Haskell expects that you write a filter, but `` x `mod` 20 `` is *not* a filter: it does *not* return a `Bool`, `` x `mod` 20 `` returns the same type of number as `x` itself.

Based on your question, you want that to be five, so can solve it with:

```
take 5 [x | x <- [0..], odd x == False, x > 0, x `mod` 13 == 3, x `mod` 20 == 5]
--                                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

But there are some other problems here:

1. you wrote "uneven", hence the `odd x` check should be `True`;
2. `x > 0` can always be `True`, given we restrict the iterator of `x` to `[1..]`;
3. we can merge `x <- [1..]` and `odd x` into `[1, 3..]`;

This results in:

```
take 5 [x | x <- [1, 3..], x `mod` 13 == 3, x `mod` 20 == 5]
```

Nevertheless we do not need all this modulo checking anyway: we can first calculate the *least common multiple* of `2` (odd constraint), `20`, and `13` which is `260`, as a result we know that the numbers in the result take "hops" of 260.

We also know that the first result is `185`, so this can be rewritten to:

```
take 5 [185, 445 ..]
```

Comment: we know that it is 185? how?

Comment: @WillNess: by interpreting it as a *linear Diophantine equation*.

Comment: @WillNess: If I find some time later today, I will try to expand the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the

```
x mod 20
```

at the end of the comprehension. You do not compare it to anything, so it fails as a condition to filter your list.